# Rails 4 - Bootstrap multiple handlers on click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I made a clean workplace to test my code. When my coffeescript was not here, bootstrap scripts were able to switch between tabs, while if I hook the coffeescript to views, bootstrap scripts refused to work. Only my coffeescript worked. I didn't know any reason that only one handler can be bind to an event. What's going on?

```
# application.js
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

# welcome_controller.rb
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def preview
    @body = params[:raw_data]
    @preview = "preview: " + @body + "..."
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
    end
  end
end

# welcome.coffee
window.Welcome = 
  hookPreview: (tab, textarea) ->
    $(tab).bind "click", ->
      Welcome.preview $(textarea).val()
      return false

$(document).ready ->
  Welcome.hookPreview $("#preview-tab"), $("#edit")
```

And my views:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#edit" data-toggle="tab" id="edit-tab">Edit</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#preview" data-toggle="tab" id="preview-tab">Preview</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- panel for tabs -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">HOME</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="edit"><textarea rows="20" class="form-control"></textarea></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="preview">PREVIEW</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Click on preview tab sends data to my controller, but it doesn't switch tabs anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `return true` instead.  False stops event propagation, so if that event gets called first, no others will.